# how to increase bottom offset for TabBar item title swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to increase space at the bottom for all the `TabBar` items instead of using the `default`. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the item.
2. Go to *Attribute inspector*.
3. Check for the property - **Title position**.
4. It is set *Default position*.

[image]

5. Change that to **Custom Offset**.

[image]

6. Now you can change the vertical and horizontal offsets.

[image]